# How to disable the shortcut for showing developer tools in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

How to disable the shortcut for showing developer tool in Google Chrome?

I hate the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. I never use the dev tools. So I would like to disable that shortcut.

Comment: Hello, what's the goal here? Why not just stop using that shortcut? "I hate it" is not reall an accurate and reasonable reason to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to do this by using this code:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
^+i::
Return
#IfWinActive
```